# Using source link configuration for mapping source with sourceFileMap in the launch.json doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have been trying to use the sourceFileMap json config without success with vs code to debug a .net 7 nuget package dll from another .net 7 project.

The sourceFileMap configuration is set in the launch.json but the map doesn't seems to work and get pick up by vs code and c# extension.

Source link look to be well configured but the file cannot load the bitbucket because of authentication issues. That's i try to use the alternative explained in [Source map documentation][1]

Is there a way to diagnostic the problem with the source map and is there a documentation explaining with a real use case?

I read the foo example but what is the "c:\foo" in the case the dll is build on a build server does it represent the original build path?

```
"sourceFileMap": {
    "C:\\foo":"/home/me/foo"
}
```

I have tried to set some key map but keep receiving Error: Unable to Locate Source File message because of authentication issue so it's look like the map not working.

```
    "sourceFileMap": {       
"https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/XYX/Project/src/5040ef34b3a083b7789eaa711f03a58319c03db4/": "G:\\Git\\LOCAL\\Project\\"

    },
```

> ### Error: Unable to Locate Source File
>
> The source file you're trying to access, located at
> '/_/src/Project/Test.cs', cannot be found on this computer. The
> debugger attempted to download the source file using Source Link, but
> the request failed.
>
> Possible Reasons:
>
> - The server requires authentication, but the VS Code C# debugger doesn't support authentication. See:
>   https://aka.ms/VSCode-DotNet-SourceLinkAuthNotSupported
> - The source control commit that this module was built from doesn't exist on the server. For example, if this module was compiled on a
>   developer's computer, the source commit might have been temporary or
>   never pushed to the server.
>
> What to Do: Manually obtain source code, for example by cloning the
> appropriate repo locally, and use `sourceFileMap` to point the
> debugger at the source code. See
> https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-SourceFileMap for complete instructions.
>
> Error Details: The request failed with HTTP status code 404
> (NotFound).
>
> The URL where the source file will be downloaded from:
> https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/XYX/Project/src/5040ef34b3a083b7789eaa711f03a58319c03db4/src/Project/Test.cs
>
> For more information about Source Link and VS Code see
> https://aka.ms/VSCode-DotNet-SourceLink